# How to paint an MFC element?

Tags: mfc

I'm not very good at MFC.
All i want to do is paint element (button, for example) when the button was pressed. I found this, but it only works when rendering dialog.

```
HBRUSH CSmartDeviceDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
   if (nCtlColor==CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
   { 
      return  a;
   }
   if (nCtlColor==CTLCOLOR_EDIT){  
      return  a;
   }
   return CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);;
}
```

Give me some advice how do I change it to smth like this:

```
void CSmartDeviceDlg::OnClick()
{
    //some code to paint my elements
}
```

Thx for future responses and do not judge strictly =)

Comment: This approach does not work with push buttons, even though there is a notification for that. You need to create an owner draw button and paint it yourself.

Comment: It will not work with statics, edit boxes etc too ?

Answer (score 0):

You should obviously place the button on the dialog somewhere physically. Code wise you should override the button onDraw to draw a custom button.

What you will achieve depends on what you want to do with the button, you can override as low as the actual drawing rectangle which represents the button and draw over it whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [invalidate the rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f3csed3.aspx) occupied by your elements to force windows to repaint them, like

```
CRect rcElement;
GetDlgItem(IDC_ELEMENT)->GetWindowRect(&rcElement); // in screen coordinates
ScreenToClient(&rcElement); // convert to client coordinates
InvalidateRect(&rcElement);
```

Note that this can cause "flickering" of the elements because the background will be erased before the elements are repainted.